# Traffic via local proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, cisco, vnc, traffic

There is any way to "redirect" all traffic through HTTP local proxy?

I did that once but the software I used was not free so the time ran out and I need to use VNC and SSH to my raspberry pi at home.

But, I study on academy Networking and Programming we have 3 Networks:

1- GRSIP (this is a ADSL connection for CISCO classes (like me) to use)
   -IP range: 192.168.27.0/24 proxy on .222

2- CISCO (this is for exams on the academy and training too)

3- DOM (this network is for the rest of non-networking and programming classes. I can't use any traffic except HTTP and some stuff is blocked of course :D
   -IP range is all 172.34.0.0/16

So, I want to do this on DOM network because sometimes we are on some rooms with only this network. I can only use the HTTP local proxy to access the filtered WWW but I really need to bypass this.

The software I remember is "your-freedom" and "proxifier" (I don't know how to work with this one).

The network map on DOM is something like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/cyrO3JU.png]

the others networks I said are separated physically.

The program I use to connect to SSH is Putty because there we use windows 7 on the physical machine. VNC I use the 5800 port (via browser with java) of my PC at home.

Anybody with ideas?

int3